# Chatter Plus to Chatter Free

Tags: administration, licenses

Quick question i've got a group of users who only chatter in one group and i want to move them from Chatter plus to chatter free because of that reason. How can i downgrade users without recreating them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible currently, as pointed out here in the SF help:
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=collab_faq_chatterplus_downgrade_to_chatter_free.htm&language=en_US

There's an idea to get it made possible:
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000KUIzAAO